# Defining functor for hom-tensor relation

Tags: category-theory, functors

I am trying to understand the hom-tensor relation and as usual I'm having a hard time defining functors on the functions.

So I have a functor $$(F:= ){_A\text{Hom}}(-,-):{_A\text{Mod}_B}^{op}\times {_A\text{Mod}_C}\rightarrow {_B\text{Mod}_C}$$ the actions on objects is clear:
$$F(M,N) = {_A\text{Hom}(M,N)}$$
However, what is the action on functions?
I take $$f\in \text{Hom}_{{_A\text{Mod}_B}^{op}}(M,M'),g\in \text{Hom}_{{_A\text{Mod}_C}}(N,N')$$
Then $(f,g)\in \text{Hom}_{{{_A\text{Mod}_B}^{op}}\times{_A\text{Mod}_C}}((M,N),(M',N'))$

and want to define $$F(f,g):{_A\text{Hom}(M,N)}\rightarrow {_A\text{Hom}(M',N')}$$
How does this work?

**EDIT**

after writing things down properly, it makes sense:

if $h$ is from $M$ to $N$ then define it's image as $g\circ h\circ f$

Comment: The primes switch side in the type ascription for $f$ and $g$ because you have $f : M' \to M$ and $g : N \to N'$ and ${}_A\text{Hom}(-,-)$ is contravariant in the first argument, so $F(f,g) : {}_A\text{Hom}(M,N)\to{}_A\text{Hom}(M',N')$. So the "inconsistent" use of primes in the types of $f$ and $g$ is to produce a consistent use in the type of $F(f,g)$. Alternatively, if you want to be consistent in a different way, then you have $f:M'\to M$ in ${}_A\text{Mod}_B^{op}$, i.e. $f : M\to M'$ in ${}_A\text{Mod}_B$.

Comment: I'll edit my question to be more precise

Comment: Ok it becomes clear when you right it down :) thanks

Comment: @DerekElkins is my edit correct?

Comment: Basically, yes. Since all the arrows are in different categories, you can't just compose them but you can compose their underlying functions as you've shown. You technically still have a proof obligation that the result is, in fact, a module homomorphism of the appropriate sort.